# RewriteCondition in .htaccess except for one folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to do the following:

I have a htaccess file that makes every request go trough `index.php`. If I am not mistaken this is called bootstrapping? (I haven't done this before).

I would like to make a subdirectory in the root directory of the site that will serve as a "test" site because I cannot add a subdomain. I need a htaccess rewritecond that will redirect any request under the `teszt` folder to the `index.php` in the same folder.

So if I enter `example.com/[anything]` I get data sent to the `index.php` in the root and if I enter `example.com/teszt/[anything]`, the data needs to be sent to `teszt/index.php`

This is my htaccess file:

```
IndexIgnore *
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Please go read [ask], among other things it has hints on how a halfway sensible question title should be phrased.

Comment: Copy the whole last block of RewriteConds + RewriteRule, and then in the _first_ one, change the rule to `RewriteRule ^teszt/(.+)$ teszt/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` (This would get you the `foobar` part of `teszt/foobar` in the `url` parameter, should you need the `teszt/` in there as well, then make the grouping braces wrap around the whole thing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in htaccess in your root folder :

```
RewriteEngine On
#rewrite /subfolder/foobar to /subfolder/index.php
ReweriteRule !subfolder/index\.php /subfolder/index.php [L]
#rewrite /foobar to /index.php
RewriteRule !index\.php /index.php [L]
```

The rules above also rewrites your existent files to index.php . If you do not want to rewrite your files , just add a condition to the rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` .

Answer (score 0):

**Though it is a very old post but someone like me might find it useful:**

`.htaccess` should be placed in the **parent** or **root** folder and should contain the following code to work properly

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /teszt/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note that for `RewriteRule` it requires a `/` before the sub directory `teszt` and `index.php?url=$1`

Thanks to [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe)